# N+1 selection in query when use Include and AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have next relation (just example) User 0/1 - * Story
I make next query when want to get list of stories with included users .

```
context.Stories.Include(s => s.User).AsNoTracking().ToList()
```

I noticed that ef makes additional requests to db for getting users (but this shouldn't be since I use include).
All works fine without AsNoTracking().

Looks that issue with nullable relations since relations that dont allow null works fine.

Does anyone have similar issues? 
Probably it is expected behaviour in case of "allow null" relation.

Comment: Can you explain your issue more clearly ? At least for me it's not clear.

Comment: You include Owner and you get users. Typing mistake ?

Comment: @tschmit007 User is domain and Owner - is name of property.
I have changed it to User in order to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Entity framework 6 (6.1.3)

Comment: No, this is not expected behavior. What does the first query look like (as SQL)? It should have an outer join to User.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly turn off Lazy Loading as below:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

EF will then not lazily load any further entities. You should check if you aren't inadvertently lazily loading some other linked entities.